# how to create multithreading in vc++

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-c++

```
void CVivantAppDBMView::OnBnClickedCalculateButton()
{

cc.Calculate(&myInputs);//Call to DLL

COutputDialog outputDialog;
        outputDialog.DoModal();
}
```

Hi ,

On button click , i have to call a function in dll . On returning i have to show the output in the dialog. please see the above code.

But when i click , before dll call finishes,dialog is opening.

Please recommend some tutorials or examples or anyother way of doing.

Im an amateur vc++ programmer.

Thanks in advance!
Selva

Comment: This is not possible. The dialog will be opened after the return from `cc.Claculate`. Check in the debugger.

Comment: Thanks @KirillKobelev i will check again in my evening.

Comment: Does `cc.Calculate()` load the DLL asynchronously? Maybe you should provide this code as well to get further help.

Comment: Yes @user0815. I am loading it async. Its just a mathmatical calculation function which is declared and defined inside the DLL. Using .h interface im calling it.

Comment: @SelvaKumar: If you just call a function inside `cc.Calculate` this behavior is not possible at all. It can only happen if a separate thread is running somewhere inside `cc.Calculate`. We need more code to help you.

Comment: @user0815 @  Kirill Kobelev Thanks for both. Actually the problem is with the thread inside Calculate.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the thread created inside the Calculate. When i fixed it, dialog open with the result once it returned from DLL.

Thanks for your help!! and Sorry for late response.

Regards,
Selva